# Pressure canner physics

Tags: pressure

I have this pressure canner at home which unfortunately does not include a thermometer. The vessel has a volume of 18 liters. The procedure that I am following is this : pouring 3 litres of water inside it with the lid slightly open and waiting for the water to boil. After it boils I wait for around 10 minutes so that any air trapped inside the canner is squeezed out. Afterwards I close the lid. Can I assume that if I reach 1 bar pressure inside the pressure canner I will have 120 degrees Celsius inside it?

PS: I live at an altitude of around 700 meters.

Comment: That's approximately correct.  But http://cooking.stackexchange.com might be a better fit.  The details of your specific canner and the procedure matter significantly.  Physics isn't a good fit for those portions.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Thank you! I just posted the question to the cooking part of the exchange.